# Android Percent Support Library Blank Screen on Actual Device

Tags: android, android-support-design

I tried using the Percent Support Library as detailed [here](https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample) and [here](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en). It works nicely in the Android Studio designer, but when I try to install my app into my phone, nothing is showing but an empty screen. What might the problem be?

**Edit:**

I've added the following lines in my gradle file dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'
```

And here is my fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="org.atpms.fairfare.ReportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_report" >

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/report_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/report_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/reportButton"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/report_background"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/report"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/report_background"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/report_background"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/report_background"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/report_background"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/report_background"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/report_background">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/plateNumberField"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="58%"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="14%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="20%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="36%"
                    android:textColor="@color/plate_number"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    tools:ignore="TextFields"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/meterPictureButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="12%"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="15.5%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="38%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="84%"
                    android:src="@drawable/camera" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/meterPicture"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="97.2%"
                    app:layout_heightPercent="42%"
                    app:layout_marginTopPercent="55.8%"
                    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="1.6%"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reportButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/report"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/report_button"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update:**

Ok, I've inflated the exact same layout from an `Activity` using `setContentView`, and it works fine. It seems that the problem only arises when I try to use the `PercentRelativeLayout` in a `Fragment` layout. It appears that `LayoutInflater` isn't correctly inflating a layout with `PercentRelativeLayout` elements, but I'm still unsure and continuing to investigate.

Comment: post some code. Also check out this demo http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-percent-support-lib-sample.html if your missing something :-)

Comment: Hi @nitesh, thanks for your response. I've edited my answer to include the relevant code.

Comment: Its time to report a bug for PercentRelativeLayout inflating issues in Fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a very nice solution, but I solved this problem by just getting rid of the fragment, and making it a full-blown activity.

Comment: Please file a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues with a small example of the problem (so I can reproduce this). If LayoutInflater indeed can't handle percent layout, I will try to fix that.

Comment: solution must work for fragments as problem indicates. Getting rid of the fragment for activity is not a solution. it has always worked for Activity